# Apache to serve Django project on EC2 instance -- 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django, apache

I am trying to deploy my Django project on AWS and have Apache serve up my webpages. I am able to deploy the webpages using runserver but I want this to become a production server --thus I want to use Apache. I am receiving a `500 Internal Server error` and don't know why.

In my project folder I have a `django.wsgi` file:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('home/ubuntu/venv/hde_nate')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='web.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application=django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

My /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
<Directory /home/ubuntu/venv/hde_nate/web>
Order allow, deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/venv/hde_nate/web/django.wsgi
alias /static /home/ubuntu/venv/hde_nate/web
```

I have a /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/django.conf, but am not sure if this file is necessary:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/venv/hde_nate/web/django.wsgi
alias /static /home/ubuntu/venv/hde_nate/web
```

To install apache I used these commands on my linux box:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

settings.py

```
DEBUG = FALSE
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = FALSE
```

Edit:
My error.log:

```
[notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: like @LukasGraf said, look in /var/log/apache2; however, i bet your not activating the virtual environment in the wsgi file: execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate_this.py))

Comment: Here's what the log file says. James_R, I'm not understanding the command you posted. Do I place this at the end of my wsgi file? I read on the django doc to include this: WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com:/path/to/your/venv/lib/python2.X/site-packages in my httpd.conf. Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Could you tell us what version of Apache you are using and server its installed on?

Comment: Apache 2.2 and the the server is an Ubuntu 12 LTS. Hope that answers the question.

Comment: unless you have not showed it in your example I don't see where you have given Apache access to django.wsgi directory i.e. Order allow,deny. Also you need to check your logs to tell us what the actual error is. If it's a django error just make the debug = True so you can see the error. Otherwise view your error logs if have not set one add ErrorLog /yourpatch/logs/error.log to your httpd.conf

Comment: Thanks Glyn. I have the order, allow, deny in the httpd.conf file as noted in my post. I also added the errors I found in my error.log found in  /var/log/apache2. Let me know if that is the correct place to look for them. I didn't set a place for my error log to be stored but I assume that the /var/log/apache2 is the default location. Correct me if I'm wrong about anything. I'm fairly new to setting this up.

Comment: Updated error log. Any ideas?

Comment: You still have deny,allow it should be allow,deny

Comment: Should have changed it on the post, but I the allow, deny didn't work. I think the problem is my directory structure. I wrote another post that's clearer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041467/django-deployment-with-apache-on-aws-directory-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Added this to my virtualhost:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API