# Django deployment with Apache on AWS -- Directory Structure

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-web-services, apache2

I have a django app with the following structure

```
web/
   manage.py
   settings.py
   wsgi.py
   urls.py
   /subapp1/
   /subapp2/
```

When deployed on the development server `runserver`, everything links and works correctly. When I deploy the entire `web` app, none of my webpages are served. There is no `500` or `404` error. And the error logs only show:

```
[notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I have the following set up for my Apache2.2.2:

wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys
import site

site.addsitedir('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/var/www/ec2-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/')
sys.path.append('/var/www/ec2-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/web')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "web.settings")

activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/ec2-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/web/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/ec2-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/web:/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
alias /static /var/www/ec2-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/web/static

<Directory /var/www/ec2-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/web>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order allow, deny
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/ec2-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/ec2-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/web:/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName ec2-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/ec2-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/web
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/ec2-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/web/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/ec2-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/web>
        <Files wsgi.py>
              Order allow,deny
              Allow from all
        </Files>
        </Directory>
```

I did a  `sudo a2ensite ec2-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` to have the site-enabled.

How do I get my webpages served by Apache? I realize this may be a weird file structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your wsgi.py with a WSGI hello world and take Django out of the picture.

If that works then one possibility is the third party extension modules you are using are not compatible with Python sub interpreters and are dead locking, causing the server to hang on the request and not return anything. For more details see:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

Make sure you try that hello world WSGI application first though rather than just jump to trying the solution described in that documentation.

Comment: Thanks Graham. The WSGI hello world app works like a charm. I'll look into the link to find some answers.

Comment: According to the link, I was missing a `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` in my VirtualHost. Everything works now, Thanks!